# Want to create a condition that checks were the input is a integer ranging from 1 to 5

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I Want to create a condition that checks were the input is a integer ranging from 1 to 5.

but it keeps saying input matching exception, can you guys help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//scanner for input
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println(">> You have selected ["+choice+"]");

//loops until input is an integer ranging from 1 to 5
while(!scan.hasNextInt() && choice>0 && choice<6){
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            databaseInsertRecord();
            break;
        case 2:
            databaseSelectAll();
            break;
        case 3:
            databaseSearchRecord();
            break;
        case 4:
            databaseUpdateRecord();
            break;
        case 5:
            databaseDeleteRecord();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println(">> You put wrong input");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like java. Not javascript

Comment: You're not assigning to `choice` in the loop, so it keeps using the first input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //scanner for input
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //input variable
    String in;

    //loops until input is an integer ranging from 1 to 5
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) { //checks if there is a new line of input
        in = scan.nextLine().trim(); //scans that line
        if (!in.matches("^[1-5]$")) { //tests if input is a single positive digit 1-5
            System.out.println(">> You put wrong input");
            continue;
        }
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(in);
        System.out.println(">> You have selected ["+choice+"]");
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                databaseInsertRecord();
                break;
            case 2:
                databaseSelectAll();
                break;
            case 3:
                databaseSearchRecord();
                break;
            case 4:
                databaseUpdateRecord();
                break;
            case 5:
                databaseDeleteRecord();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have slightly altered your code to not only keep persisting the user for a valid input, but also correctly parse that input to avoid any errors. I also removed the `default` part of the switch block, only because the input validation prior eliminates the need for it.

I have not tested this code, but it should work properly :)

Answer (score 0):

You are currently not updating the *choice* variable for each iteration, but rather only using the initial value. Furthermore, you're iterating until *scan* **DOES NOT** have an *int*, i.e. `!scan.hasNextInt()` and I guess you're intention is actually the opposite.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //scanner for input
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice; 
   //loops until input is an integer ranging from 1 to 5
   while(scan.hasNextInt() && (choice = scan.nextInt()) > 0 && choice < 6){
       switch (choice) {
           case 1:
               databaseInsertRecord();
               break;
           case 2:
               databaseSelectAll();
               break;
           case 3:
               databaseSearchRecord();
               break;
           case 4:
               databaseUpdateRecord();
               break;
           case 5:
               databaseDeleteRecord();
               break;
           default:
               System.out.println(">> You put wrong input");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!